# Cannot make plotted variable dynamically selectable in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

## Aim

I have two data tables: `DT1` and `DT2`. Each has one X-variable: `x`, and three Y-variables: `y1`, `y2` and `y3`. My aim is to create a basic Shiny app where both the dataset and the Y-variable are selectable by the user.

## Minimal example

#### Data

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

#y1 between 1 and 50
DT1 <- data.table(x=c(1:10),
                 y1 = round(runif(10, 1, 50)))

#y2 between 51 and 100
DT2 <- data.table(x=c(1:10),
                  y1 = round(runif(10, 51, 100)))

#y2 and y3 are double and triple multiples of y1
DT1[, y2 := y1*2][, y3 := y1*3]
DT2[, y2 := y1*2][, y3 := y1*3]
```

#### Version 1: Only the data input

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = 'input1', label = 'Choose a data table',
              choices = c("1st" = "data1", "2nd" = "data2")),
  plotOutput(outputId = "graph")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$graph <- renderPlot({ 
    dt <- switch(input$input1, data1=DT1, data2=DT2) #data switch
    ggplot(dt, aes(x, y1)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So far, so good. The app works and the data table being plotted is selectable by the user.

[image: shiny1]

#### Version 2: Adding the Y-variable input

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = 'input1', label = 'Choose a data table',
              choices = c("1st" = "data1", "2nd" = "data2")),
  selectInput(inputId = 'input2', label = 'Choose a Y-variable',
              choices = c("Y-1" = "Y_1", "Y-2" = "Y_2", "Y-3" = "Y_3")),
  plotOutput(outputId = "graph")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$graph <- renderPlot({ 
    dt <- switch(input$input1, data1=DT1, data2=DT2) #data switch
    var <- switch(input$input2, Y_1=y1, Y_2=y2, Y_3=y3) #Y-variable switch
    ggplot(dt, aes(x, var)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This doesn't work!

[image: shiny2]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`y1` doesn't exist in the environnement where you calling it, it works in ggplot2 `aes` and in data.table `[` because these functions use non standard evaluation.

For solving your problem, do :

```
var <- switch(input$input2, Y_1 = "y1", Y_2 = "y2", Y_3 = "y3")
ggplot(dt, aes_string("x", var)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

The `switch` step is optionnal if you redefine choice in ui, e.g. : `choices = c("Y-1" = "y1", "Y-2" = "y2", "Y-3" = "y3")`, and in server : `ggplot(dt, aes_string("x", input$input2)) + geom_point() + geom_line()`.

You can read :

- http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html